# Thread safe Observer pattern in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I write an observer pattern in multithreaded application and I wonder if my implementation will working correct:

```
    private void notifyObservers() {
        Set<Observer> localObservers;

        synchronized(MONITOR) {
            if (mObservers != null) 
                observersCopy = new HashSet<>(observers);
        }

        for (Observer observer : localObservers) { 
            observer.update();
        }
    }
```

Is my thinking correct:

```
1. Thread A call notifyObservers().
2. Thread B call notifyObservers().
3. Thread A comes in synchronized section and hold lock.
4. Thread B is waiting before synchronized section.
5. Thread A creates his own copy of observers and leaves a synchronized section.
6. Thread B comes in synchronized section and hold lock, creates his own copy of observers and leaves a synchronized section.
7. Both threads notifies observers on their own copies.
```

And my question is whether these copies of `observers` are existing only in local memory of the thread thread that created the copy? Does it mean that Thread A has independent and not shared copy of observers and Thread B has also independent and not shared copy?

Comment: Your reasoning is correct. But your code doesn't even compile, and its correctness also depends on what you're doing in the remaining of the code (adding listeners, etc.), and on the implementation of the observers (which must be thread-safe, too).

Comment: Ok, thanks. But if my Observers would not implement Runnable would I have to implement them thread safe or not?

Comment: Whether your observers implement Runnable or not is irrelevant. They're called concurrently by several threads, so they need to be thread-safe.

Comment: Ok, I understand.